# PHP Site integration to Thingsboard using Google oAuth, without asking user to login everytime

Tags: php, google-oauth, openid, google-api-php-client, thingsboard

I am trying to use google oAuth - openid to link Thingsboard (IoT open source) with one another site. I am able to do that successfully once, when I login to google account. But my requirement is to use the auth code / access token next time and get the request authenticated. User should not be asked to login to the google account again.

Code:

```
<?php
ob_start();
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setApplicationName("My APP");
$client->setClientId('Redacted');
$client->setClientSecret('Redacted');
$client->setRedirectUri('REDIRECT URLS'); //This same page.
$client->setAccessType("offline");
$client->addScope("email");
$client->addScope("profile");
$client->addScope("openid");
$client->setPrompt("consent");
$client->setApprovalPrompt("force");
$strtoken = getToken();//This will get the token from the file, if token exists.

if($strtoken <> '') //If the token exists retrived from the file, no need to ask user to login. 
{​​​​
    $new_token = "";
    $accessToken="";
    echo "strtoken" . $strtoken;
    $accessToken = json_decode(file_get_contents("/home/www/token.txt"), true);
    $ref_token = $accessToken['refresh_token'];
    $access_token= $accessToken['access_token'];

    $client->setAccessToken($accessToken);
    if ($client->isAccessTokenExpired()) {​​​​
        $client->fetchAccessTokenWithRefreshToken($client->getRefreshToken());
        updateToken(json_encode($client->getAccessToken()));
    }​​​​
    header("Location: IOT URL"); //The Thingsboard home page url. 
    die;
}​​​​

if(isset($_GET['code']))
{​​​​
    $client->authenticate($_GET['code']);
    $arrtoken = $client->getAccessToken();
    $access_token = $arrtoken['access_token'];
    $tokens_encoded = json_encode($arrtoken);
    $client->setAccessToken($arrtoken['access_token']);
    updateToken($tokens_encoded);
    header("Location: IOT URL");//The Thingsboard home page url. 
    die();
}​​​​
if($strtoken == "" && !(isset($_GET['code'])))
{​​​​?>
    <a class="login-btn" href="<?php echo $client->createAuthUrl(); ?>">Login</a><br>
<?php}​​​​
function updateToken($token)
{​​​​
    $myfile = fopen("token.txt", "w+");
    fwrite($myfile, $token); 
    fclose($myfile);
}​​​​

function getToken()
{​​​​
    $token = "";
    $filename = "/home/www/token.txt";
    $fh = fopen($filename,'r');
    while ($line = fgets($fh)) 
    {​​​​
      $token  = $line;
    }​​​​
    fclose($fh);    
    return $token;    
}​​​​
?>
```

Comment: you appear to be storing the $ref_token it should be grabbing a new access token for you.  Are you getting any error message?

Comment: Thanks Daimto. No as such it is not giving any error message, but it is asking to enter google credentials again when the session is destroyed and cookies are cleared. As I mentioned, I do not wish to ask user to login to google account again as I have the access token, which was fetched on the first time.

Comment: What is in token.txt can you post the contents.   make sure that $client->getRefreshToken() is set. You need to be loading it from token.txt file

Comment: token.txt contains the access token received from the google on first time. It is something like as below. ```{​​​"access_token":"value from google","expires_in":3599,"refresh_token":"1\/\/03lPR6PtzssfdC value from google","scope":"https:\/\/www.googleapis.com\/auth\/userinfo.profile openid https:\/\/www.googleapis.com\/auth\/userinfo.email","token_type":"Bearer","id_token":"eyJhbGciOiJSU.d5T1wFdvKSy5Jf08DJ_XAS-x-EOE a long value from google","created":1642068657}​​​```

Comment: Check answer my comment got to long (❁´◡`❁)

Answer (score 0):

I can see from comments that you appear to have a refresh token in that file.  That's good now check that the refresh token is in this value $ref_token = $accessToken['refresh_token'];  So $ref_token should be the same value thats in the the file.

Once thats done you need to make sure that its set on the client

```
$client->refreshToken($ref_token);
```

Once that is set you should be able to use

```
$client->fetchAccessTokenWithRefreshToken($client->getRefreshToken());
```

Remember though if you get a expired token at this point its the refresh token thats expired and you need to authorize the user again to request a new one.

## clarification.

From comments i think you are a little confused as to what your code is going to allow you to do.

```
$client->addScope("email");
$client->addScope("profile");
$client->addScope("openid");
```

What you are doing is requesting authorization of the user to access their profile data. This means that you could use the Google people api to request information of the user.  your app has been granted consent to access the users data this is called Authorization.

The following statement from comments

> When I redirect the user to Thingsboard dashboard url, it is not recognizing this oauth user and throws to login page.

In order to access a Thingsboard Dashboard, your user needs to be logged into Thingsboard.  This is called Authentication or signin you are authenticating that the user behind the machine is in in fact the owner of the account, they have a login and password so they can sign in.

The first thing you need to understand that authorization and authencation are two different things.

Then you need to understand as far as authentication goes. Google and Thingsboard are two different companies.  They each have their own authorization server which allow their users to sign in to their applications.

Google can not help you sign in to Thingsboard web app only Thingsboard has access to do that.

So no php code you can create using a Google Oauth is going to allow you to signin to Thingsboard web application.

Comment: Thanks Daimto! I have applied that and then I have used : ```$payload = $client->verifyIdToken($new_accessToken['id_token']);``` Now, it gives me the profile data and other user data in $payload. It is working fine upto that. When I redirect the user to Thingsboard dashboard url, it is not recognizing this oauth user and throws to login page. Now, it seems it's the Thingsboard issue.

Comment: Please check my update the clarification section.

Comment: Thank you so much! I understand that. I know they are two different applications and google can't help me directly to access Thingsboard. Why I am a bit optimistic is, Thingsboard also allow sign in using oAuth. It has that feature. You need to provide the oAuth provider, their urls for access token, authorization, JWT and user info. Also basic mappings for the google user and thingsboard user. Those all settings are done. Even, on the first time, when user enters the  google account details, it does authorizes the request and displays the Thingsboard dashboard.

Comment: Authorization needs to go though ThingBoards auth server not googles.    Any authorization you get from google will have google as the authority Thingboard isn't going to accept that.   Go though Thingboard authorization server. strop trying to connect to googles authorization server.